# passing a long xml string to href

Tags: html, jsp

I am trying to pass a very long xml string through href from a jsp page.
But when i am clicking on the link its displaying just a blank page.
This link should basically take me to a spring controller but isn't going there.
Is there any limit on the length of param being passed in URL. And if so how can we pass it from a web page.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the standards don't dictate it there is a limit to the length of an URI it differs per browser but the general consensus is 2048 bytes. You should POST your XML data.